# How to load a pkcs12 from database in python

Tags: django, pkcs#12

I want to parse a pkcs12 file from my database, I uses the command `load_pkcs12`
but this one, takes a file in parameters or I want to use an object from database that I got with `get` query. How do I need to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
blob_file = Xx.objects.get(id=X_id).pkcs12
p12 = load_pkcs12(blob_file,'password')
```